# F# Data Types + SQL-Server Persistence (using No-SQL techniques)

Tags: f#, f#-data, xml-database

My F# application has a very well-shaped F# model, taking full advantage of the F# type system (unions, records, tuples and primitive types). I'm trying to figure out the best way to persist these data types to a SQL-Server DB.

Let's make the following assumptions:

- The central entity I want to persist is a Discriminated Union, called `Task`, which has about 30 different union cases, each case with wildly different properties (which may be other DUs, records or tuples or primitive types), that makes using a rectangular-relational table very tedious to implement
- I expect to be constantly evolving these models, multiple times a week, with CI set to deploy my app to production immediately upon commit. Again, using a regular table will make `ALTER TABLE` statements slow down my development and deployments and adds a considerable amount of cognitive overload that any new developers ramping up on this system will find challenging
- Upon model evolution, I should be easily able to upgrade my old models online using a background process, or upon fetch from the DB, with close-to-0 downtime
- I should be able to query into these models at arbitrary depth, and I already have close to a million rows to deal with, and this will keep growing. Querying should be fast, in the order of hundred milliseconds at most
- I need to use SQL Server, as this application is a small part of a larger system, and I would like any DB operations to participate in any ongoing DB transactions

---

### Serializing `Task` to JSON

This was my first attempt -- store everything as JSON, identify queryable values, store them in an indexed table, using SQL Server 2016's new JSON functions. JSON functions in SQL Server are extremely fast, however indexing these queries requires that I either use persisted+computed+indexed columns or indexed views.

Pains:

- Very hard to evolve models, especially if I want to evolve all instances of type X, which may appear at various depths for different union cases. There is no standardized language to spec out these evolutions
- JSON doesn't differentiate between decimal / floats / numbers, and this is sometimes a pain to deal with, and I need custom formatters. Small issue, no big deal.
- Query language is somewhat primitive at an arbitrary depth, and these queries aren't indexed, so a new query will almost always require that I create a computed column or alter my indexed view.
- Adding a new indexed column to the indexed view is not an ONLINE operation and results in downtime, and is very difficult to automate in CI
- Using PERSISTED COLUMNS within the same table sometimes leads to SQL Server not really using these while searching / selecting, and instead re-calculating the values from scratch (because it doesn't accurately calculate the cost of this operation very well in its query planner)

---

### Serializing `Task` to XML

This is my current implementation.

- I've written my own custom XML serializers that make it very easy for me to query into the DB using XQuery and SQL Server's xml datatype columns
- Model evolutions are a breeze, using extremely-powerful XSLT

Problems:

- Query, even with all possible XML indices added is slow -- takes about 5 seconds (in Azure P6 SQL instances)
- Couple this with slightly different queries for different persisted model versions, and it makes it even more expensive
- Non-indexed XML Functions are very slow, and it takes forever to build out indexed tables / persisted columns, so I can't really use this.

---

I'm quite happy with my XML solution -- I just need a way to make my XML queries faster, and I think at this point, I've hit the limits of what SQL Server can offer.

Are there any other approaches that I've missed that the F# community has tried to be able to persist a very rich F# data model?

Comment: There are some apparently-good JSON serialization libraries at https://github.com/haf/Newtonsoft.Json.FSharp (wait, that project's README says it is deprecated in favor of https://github.com/xyncro/chiron instead). I say "apparently" only because I've never tried them. However, it sounds like your difficulty stems more from "SQL Server doesn't deal very well with queries on deeply-nested JSON structures" than from "I'm having trouble serializing my data to JSON", so that may not help you much. Not being an expert on SQL Server, though, it's the best I can do.